# Error in syntax in MySQL: AS statement

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

This SQL query works perfectly well when I remove the `AS` clause.

```
$query = "SELECT bd_brushname FROM tbl_brushdescription WHERE MATCH(bd_brushname, bd_brushdescription) AGAINST ('brushes' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS rank";
    $sqlquery = mysql_query($query);
    if($sqlquery === FALSE){
        die(mysql_error()); 
    }
```

And when I use `AS`, it says `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS rank' at line 1`

Could someone please tell me why its not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL AS in WHERE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611451/mysql-as-in-where-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are meant to be put on the columns you select, to :

- rename them on your output
- use the alias in the `order by` or `having` clause

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html?iframe=true&width=100#idp57170512)

Understanding your request, you're using an alias for a condition here, what's the point ?

What did you try to do ?

Comment: Actually i want to rank the results. I thought to do something like: `SELECT bd_brushname FROM tbl_brushdescription WHERE MATCH(bd_brushname, bd_brushdescription) AGAINST ('brushes' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS rank WHERE MATCH(bd_brushname, bd_brushdescription) AGAINST ('brushes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do, if you're trying to sort the results by relevance, you need to include the relevance itself in your selected columns : [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494460/mysql-fulltext-search-order-by-relevance)

Answer (score 0):

Change the place of "AS rank"

```
$query = "SELECT bd_brushname AS rank FROM tbl_brushdescription WHERE MATCH(bd_brushname, bd_brushdescription) AGAINST ('brushes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    $sqlquery = mysql_query($query);
    if($sqlquery === FALSE){
        die(mysql_error()); 
    }
```